# Clustering N points based on their distances

Tags: algorithm, union

I am given `n` points on a 2D grid. I am asked to cluster the points, where points with distance `<=k` for some constant `k` are grouped together. Note that all pairs of points within a cluster must adhere to the distance rule.

The way I thought about approaching this problem is, for each point, find its neighbors, where neighbors are defined by points that are within the distance `k`. We can assume each point and their initial neighbors form an initial cluster.

Then for each point, we compare its initial cluster with all of its neighbors clusters. If all of the neighbors clusters are the same as the current points cluster, then they're joined. If at least 1 of the neighbors clusters, is not the same, then all points involved and their neighbors must be disjoint.

e.g., say we have points

[0, -0.5]

[0, 0]

[0, 0.5]

[0, 1.5]

and `k = 1`

For point [0, -0.5] we have neighbors `[0, 0]` and `[0, 0.5]`.

For point [0, 0] we have neighbors `[0, 0.5]` and `[0, -0.5]`.

For point [0, 0.5] we have neighbors `[0, 0]`, `[0, -0.5]`, `[0, 1.5]`.

For point [0, 1.5] we have neighbors `[0, 0]`, `[0, 1.5]`.

So in this case, we will have 4 clusters, defined by an individual point.

What is the most efficient way to implement this algorithm?

Comment: How you get 4 clusters here? I am assuming there is only a single cluster here, as point `[0, 0.5]` have neighbors `[0, 0]`, `[0, -0.5]`, `[0, 1.5]`. So they will form a single cluster, am I right?

Comment: That point has 3 neighbors, but a cluster is defined as such that you can take any 2 points in the cluster and have the points be separated by a maximum distance of `k`. So in this case, e.g., `[0,0]` and `[0, 1.5]` wouldn't be in the same cluster since they have a distance > k.